# Facebook C# SDK with WCF service

Tags: wcf, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm interested in making a cross-platform Facebook, but non-browser based application. 
Therefor I'd like to make WCF service, which provide and hide e.g. authentication methods, queries via Graph API.
To keep it simple, firstly I would like to connect this service, with a console client.

Does anyone has a tutorial, hint, how can I manage this?

I started with this simple demo app: 
http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Writing-your-First-Facebook-Application-v6.aspx
The main problem with it, that it is using webbrowser control, which I can hardly imagine on a service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to create WCF Service and use it as a proxy to Facebook? You can make direct requests to Facebook server.

As for the authentication you still have to use oauth and ask user to login. You can then securely save the access token somewhere and use that access token to make the requests.

Comment: I'd like to use service, because I'm trying to develop mobile app for WP7,Android,IOS with .NET and Mono framework(MonoDroid,MonoTouch). This allow me, to share most of the code between the platforms. The only problem is, that it doesn't have a standard UI, so example webbrowser control doesn't work. So I think the easiest and cleanest way to share this part of code, to put the Facebook related things to the service, and access it via an interface, which could be shared.
But if I need to explain so much, I guess I should rethink my plans:)
Thank you your answer anyway.